# PrinterPlusPlus can't find virtual printer

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-printer

My company is trying to setup a file sharing system. That is why we decided to use a virtual printer, to send files to different locations more efficiently.

I am using PrinterPlusPlus to get the job done, but the problem is that I've found the online documentation to be quiet shallow.

Is there anybody who has any experience with this software? I can't get it to work.

*Here are a few steps I took to get where I am now (nowhere...)*

1. Install the virtual printer

[image: Installing printer]

2. Create a simple program.
3. Use the printer++ tools to link my program with the virtual printer

[image: link dll with virtual printer]

And nothing happens. I can't find the new printer in the devices, nor in the printdialogue screen in any application. Would be nice if someone with experience in this software, could point me the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been working with printer++ for some weeks, and found out some problems on the code that might help you.

- First thing you should check is 32 or 64 bit version. Happened to me that I was trying to install 32 bit version on a windows 7 64bit, and the result was that no printer is actually installed, even though the monitor works.
- Another problem might be language. In some point of the installer it checks for some error message that won't correspond if you are using windows with other language different to english. One solution to this, is to open the source code project and comment line 411 and 412 from SpoolerHelper.cs file (in my case under x64 installer). Compile, and try again.

  ```
   //1 - Add Printer Monitor
          LogHelper.Log("Adding Printer Monitor.");
          GenericResult printerMonitorResult = AddPrinterMonitor(monitorName);
          if (printerMonitorResult.Success == false)
          {
              if (printerMonitorResult.Message.ToLower() != "the specified print monitor has already been installed")
                  throw printerMonitorResult.Exception;
          }
  ```

My solution to spanish windows was:

```
 //1 - Add Printer Monitor
            LogHelper.Log("Adding Printer Monitor.");
            GenericResult printerMonitorResult = AddPrinterMonitor(monitorName);
            if (printerMonitorResult.Success == false)
            {
                if ((printerMonitorResult.Message.ToLower() != "the specified print monitor has already been installed") && (printerMonitorResult.Message.ToLower() != "el monitor de impresión especificado ya ha sido instalado"))
                    throw printerMonitorResult.Exception;
            }
```

If you are still having troubles, there is an installation logger on c:/PrinterPlusPlus_Installer.txt. Maybe you can find some answer there.

I know it's been awhile since your question but I wanted to share this anyway, for someone else that might need it. Hope it helps.

Comment: When I saw the installation logger I found this error message "Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus". Can you help me ?

Comment: @AvneeshSrivastava same problem here. Ever overcome it?

Comment: Do you have the installer of Printer++? As their website is in progress, I am not able to find that anywhere on the internet

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Here is the GitHub link https://github.com/Yiidiir/printerplusplus